FCM api v1 not sending notifications on iOS
When I try to send a push notification via FCM api v1 using Postman it fails with an error message.
Working well for Android with the same payload.
POST - https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/digital-journey-b/messages:send
body
{
  "message": {
    "token": "ea6LlJYZQXg:APA91bEGXaQrhuLpI...wBZw4SHOSWTutXzwjV3V2hEb9",
    "notification": {
      "title":"TEST",
      "body":"great match"
    }
  }
}

response
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
                "errorCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
            },
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.ApnsError"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Any help would be great.

same error. how can I fix this ?
